# Changing CSS via Javascript does NOT work in IE8 for me

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a small snippet of code that I'm running to switch some DIV tags on and off contingent upon events happening on the page. This code is as follows:

```
function toggleBack() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('innerContentForEmailCapture');
    var list2 = document.getElementsByClassName('mpRight');
    var list3 = document.getElementsByClassName('mpBtns');
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list.item(i).style.display = 'none';
        }
        for (var ii = 0; ii < list2.length; ii++) {
            list.item(ii).style.display = 'block';
        }
        for (var iii = 0; iii < list3.length; iii++) {
            list.item(iii).style.display = 'block';
        }
    } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Mind you, this code does exactly what I want it to do when it's called, **Except when dealing with ie8**. When using this code there I receive an error message that states:

***TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method***

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here.  The idea is to turn the display to *none* for any DIV with the class "innerContentForEmailCapture" and turn the display to *block* for any DIV with the classes of "mpRight" and "mpBtns".

Is there a simpler way? One that would allow the behavior to work in ie8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

this function is not supported on IE8. You'd better use

```
document.querySelectorAll
```

so you would have:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.innerContentForEmailCapture')
document.querySelectorAll('.mpBtns')
document.querySelectorAll('.mpRight')
```

Or, if you need to use getElementsByClassName you can use some polyfills like [this](https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607)

Comment: Thank you so much, Stefano! You've saved me some great time here!